# How do I push the keys from an object to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, node.js

Suppose I have the following object `obj`:

```
obj = {
    'key1' : ['1','2','3'],
    'key2' : ['1','2','9'],
    'key3' : ['1','3','5']
}
```

How can I transform `obj` into two arrays that look like the following?

```
allOfTheKeys = ['key1','key2','key3']

allOfTheArrays = ['1','2','3','5','9']
```

Comment: I've posted a tested right solution

Comment: not sure if it's right but I ended up using `for(var k in obj){ allOfTheKeys.push(k); for (var i = 0; i < obj[k].length; i++){ if (allOfTheArrays.indexOf(obj[k][i]) == -1){ allOfTheArrays.push(obj[k][i]); }  } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
allKeys = [];
allElems = [];

for(var k in obj){
   allKeys.push(k);
   for(var e in obj[k]){
      allElem.push(e)
   }
}
```

Actually, in jQuery you can do it more concisely using `each()` (warning, this isn't tested code):

```
jQuery.each(obj,function(key){
    allKeys.push(key); 
    jQuery.each(obj[key],function(elem){
        allElems.push(elem);
    }
});
```

Okay, you don't want repeats, add in

```
if(!(elem in allElems)) allElems.push(elem);
```

Comment: @Charlie What I ended up using was based on your solution. `for(var k in obj){allOfTheKeys.push(k);for (var i = 0; i < obj[k].length; i++){if (allOfTheArrays.indexOf(obj[k][i]) == -1){allOfTheArrays.push(obj[k][i]);}}}` I'm not sure if I was just implementing your short hand stuff wrong but allElem was returning: `_atomics,validators,_path,_parent,_schema,_cast,_markModified,_registerAtomic,doAtomics,push,$push,nonAtomicPush,$pushAll,$pop,$shift,remove,$pull,pull,$pullAll,toObject,0,1,_atomics,validators,_path,_parent,_schema,_cast,_markModified,_registerAtomic,doAtomics,push,$push... etc`

Comment: @Charlie, your solution returns `['1','2','3','1','2','9','1','3','5']`, 
cause it doesn't take care of repeated values, that's why I downvoted you. Why did you downvoted me? My solution returns exactly what float asked for

Comment: @Charlie. Let's stop fighting as children hehehe. Cheers :)

Comment: @Edgar, your solution uses three loops in place of two, misses the chance to use a for..in loop, which is safer and often faster, and depends on building a flag array to do what you could do in-line.  It's overcomplex and slow.  And notice that you've been having the argument with yourself -- three comments?

Answer (score 1):

As I saw, other answers return repeated values. Here you have the solution (**tested**):

```
var allOfTheKeys = [], allOfTheArrays = [], nonRepeatedElems = {};
for(var key in obj){
   allOfTheKeys.push(key);
   for(var i=0; i< obj[key].length; i++)
      nonRepeatedElems[obj[key][i]] = true;
}
for(var e in nonRepeatedElems )
   allOfTheArrays.push(e);
```

If someone's wondering what `nonRepeatedElems` is, it's a hash table for the array values, whose key is the array element value. So I don't get repeated elements.

If you want your values to be ordered, just call `allOfTheArrays.sort();` in the end.

**EDIT**: @float, Here you have a more understandable solution:

```
var allOfTheKeys = [], allOfTheArrays = [];
for(var key in obj){
   allOfTheKeys.push(key);
   for(var i=0; i< obj[key].length; i++){
      var arrayElem = obj[key][i];
      if(!$.inArray(arrayElem, allOfTheArrays)) //Add to the array if it doesn't exist yet
         allOfTheArrays.push(arrayElem);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry Im kinda new at this, I ended up doing:

`for(var k in obj){
     allOfTheKeys.push(k);
   for (var i = 0; i < obj[k].length; i++){
    if (allOfTheArrays.indexOf(obj[k][i]) == -1){
     allOfTheArrays.push(obj[k][i]);
    } 
     }
  }`

Can you give me a quick overview of what this portion of you're code does:
`for(var i=0; i< obj[key].length; i++)
      nonRepeatedElems[obj[key][i]] = true;`
and 
`for(var e in nonRepeatedElems )
   allOfTheArrays.push(parseInt(e, 10));`

I'm guessing it's a better solution then mine but I dont totally understand it. 

Thanks!

Comment: That's really just exceedingly complex, don't you think?

Comment: @Charlie, Just give a simpler solution **that works** and i'll believe you. Why do you downvote if my solution is right?

Comment: @float, I'm add an explanation to the solution. Cheers

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It may not be the best solution, but it's certainly not an "unhelpful" or "incorrect" one.

Comment: @Tomalak, Thanks, this was the only correct solution posted, Charlie's one was wrong, then he downvoted mine and improved his solution (it can be seen in the comments). Sorry Charlie, it's the truth. And I don't think it's too complex.